# Find out when does Query finish loading the latest added item

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have a function which write data into database

```
private void startCommenting() {

    final String comment_val = meditComment.getText().toString().trim();

    meditComment.setText("");

    if (!TextUtils.isEmpty(comment_val)) {

        mProgress.show();

        final DatabaseReference newPost = mComment.child(post_key).push();
        final String commentkey = newPost.getKey();

        mUser.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

                Map<String,Object> checkoutData=new HashMap<>();
                checkoutData.put("time",ServerValue.TIMESTAMP);
                newPost.setValue(checkoutData);
                newPost.child("comment").setValue(comment_val);
                newPost.child("uid").setValue(dataSnapshot.child("id").getValue());
                newPost.child("blogpost").setValue(dataSnapshot.child("blogkey").getValue());
                newPost.child("userimage").setValue(dataSnapshot.child("image").getValue());
                newPost.child("username").setValue(dataSnapshot.child("name").getValue());

            }
            @Override
            public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
            }
        });

    }
}
```

After this function was called, a Query was made to get the data which contains the right post_key in the child ("blogpost").

```
mpostComment.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {

            startCommenting();

                mQueryCurrentComment = mComment.child(post_key).orderByChild("blogpost").equalTo(post_key);

                mQueryCurrentComment.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                        String currentuserid;
                        String lastuserid = "";
                        String currentcommentuid;
                        for (DataSnapshot dsp : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                            currentuserid = dsp.child("uid").getValue().toString();

                            Log.d(TAG, "user newid: " + currentuserid);
                            Log.d(TAG, "user oldid: " + lastuserid);


                            if (currentuserid.equals(lastuserid)) {

                            } else {
                                final DatabaseReference newCommentLike = mComment.child(currentuserid).push();
                                Map<String, Object> checkTime = new HashMap<>();
                                checkTime.put("time", ServerValue.TIMESTAMP);
                                newCommentLike.setValue(checkTime);
                                newCommentLike.child("location").setValue(location_key);
                                newCommentLike.child("category").setValue(category_key);
                                newCommentLike.child("pressed").setValue("false");
                                newCommentLike.child("message").setValue(" has also commented your post. ");
                                newCommentLike.child("blogpost").setValue(post_key);
                                newCommentLike.child(post_key).setValue(true);
                            }
                            lastuserid = currentuserid;
                        }
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

                    }
                });  
        }
    });
```

However, the Query was triggered twice, one before the new item was added, another after new item was added, which looks like below:

[image: Query Log]

How can I only perform the actions inside Query after the newest item was added and not twice? Any help is appreciated!

Comment: ref.addValueEventListener will return all the data each time a value changed. you can use ref.addChildEventListener instead to get more granular updates onChildAdded etc... is this what you are trying to achieve?     here is the documentation: https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/android/lists-of-data#child-events  Retrieve lists of items or listen for additions to a list of items. This callback is triggered once for each existing child and then again every time a new child is added to the specified path. The DataSnapshot passed to the listener contains the the new child's data.

Comment: I think I can guess why your code do that. But somehow, I don't understand the final use of the second code sample you write. Did you want to check if the last person who comment is the new commenter's user? So you can put new message if it is not, and just ignore if it is?

Comment: @koceeng yes exactly. Now due to the Query was called twice, the new message can't be ignored for the first triggered.

Comment: @TomerBu if I use onChildAdded, how can I retrieve the lastuserid? I can only retrive currentuserid from dataSnapshot.child("uid").getValue

Comment: I think you can use `dataSnapshot.getChildrenCount()` to get the data count and create "fori" loop and ignore if i is not equals to total count - 1

Comment: @koceeng I dont get why total count - 1... can you explain more on that bit?